# What is the meaning of その点 in this context?

Tags: grammar, translation

Tanaka and Ohta are having a conversation about main characters anime. Tanaka comments that it looks really tiring being a main character since they have to do so many things.

Ohta replies with 「ま、活躍するのが主人公だからな」

And then Tanaka responds with the golden question:

> その点モブはいいよ

What is the translation of その点 in this case?

In that respect? On the other hand?

Comment: Literally, "that point" (is good)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> その点モブはいいよ

その点 literally means "in that point/respect" but here it means "Compared to that, ..." or "Contrary to that, ..." (≂ 「それにひきかえ」「それに比べて」). I feel like その点 in this sense is used in casual speech rather than in formal speech/writing. And it's その点 (not その点で, その点において etc.) when used in this sense.

*lit.* "Compared to *that* (= 主人公が大変なこと), minor characters are good."
"Compared to / Contrary to (being) a main character (who is busy), (being) a minor character is good (cos it's carefree / not difficult or busy.) / [Thanks to @Sjiveru] it's better to be a mob.

Comment: ぜんぜん辞書に載ってないわーー

Comment: つまり翻訳すると、「In that case, better to be a mob then」とかになるだろうね。

Comment: あ、そうかーありがとうございます！

Comment: 問題なくでーす　(o・ω・o)